# NavigationDraver как при клике использовать 1 всего Fragment и передавать туда по id информацию?

Tags: android, sql, android-sdk, android-fragment

Добрый вечер. Столкнулась с проблемой имею NavigationDraver в котором есть 6 item при клике на item должен открываться Fragment. Хочу использовать всего 1 фрагмент но в него передавать разную информацию я так понимаю что нужно как то идентифицировать фрагмент, что б при клике на 1вый айтем допустим передавало идентификато 1, при 2ом клике 2ой. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать/

Сейчас у меня вот так вот. Мне сказали что это не правильно и не нужно столько фрагментов создавать, достаточно 1ого фрагмента всего.

```
.withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    switch (drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                        case 1:
                            TabFragmentFish adapter = new TabFragmentFish(getSupportFragmentManager());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            TabFragmentAdapterPlants adapterPlants = new TabFragmentAdapterPlants(getSupportFragmentManager());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPlants);
                            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            TabFragmentWater fragmentWater = new TabFragmentWater(getSupportFragmentManager());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentWater);
                            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            TabFragmentsLight fragmentsLight = new TabFragmentsLight(getSupportFragmentManager());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentsLight);
                            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно передавать данные в новый фрагмент. Можно использовать для этого `Bundle`, можно передавать любые данные, если примитивные типы то проще, если пользовательский класс, то немного сложнее .Вот кусок примера. В моем случае я передаю класс `TexnikaSobr`.

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        Fragment_texnika_adapter_test fragment_texnika_adapter = new Fragment_texnika_adapter_test();
        fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment_texnika_adapter);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("statictika", model.getTexnika_sobr()); //Указываю что буду передавать
        fragment_texnika_adapter.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Во фрагменте я получаю данные

```
    public class Fragment_texnika_adapter_test  extends Fragment{
     private Texnika_Sobr texnika_sobr;
     //Ваши данные (Кнопки, тексты и т.д)

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_texnika_statistika_adapter, container, false);
     Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            texnika_sobr = bundle.getParcelable("statictika");
        }
//Ваш код
return view;
}
```

В моем случае я передаю класс. Для этого его нужно имплементировать `Parcelable`. Для этого есть онлайн генератор [Parcelable](http://www.parcelabler.com/), туда вставляете свой класс и генерируете новый.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать стандартную комплектацию от `AndroidStudio` `TabbedActivity`, указав в методе `getCount` адаптера нужное количество фрагментов, например:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}
```

И адаптер будет создавать фрагменты используя один макет. Затем в главный `activity_main` макет добавьте `NavigationDraver`, и в методе `onItemClick` вашего `NavigationDraver` во `ViewPager` передавайте значение, например у вас 6 пунктов в `NavigationDraver` в первом пункте указываете `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0)`, во-втором `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` и так далее до бесконечности.

Что касается передачи данных по `id` то в стандартной комплектации `TabbedActivity` уже прописана статическая переменная:

```
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
```

и есть пример с передачей данных по текущей позиции `ViewPager` из возвращаемых адаптером количеством фрагментов.

```
getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
```